# chromium-bsu on the raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, arm, games

Is it possible to run chromium-bsu (NOT the browser. The game.) on the raspberry pi? My friend tells me it needs an ARM build, and if it does but there is no ARM build, can I replace the pi's CPU with a 64-bit or 32-bit one?

Edit: I'm using the Ubuntu Mate OS for the pi.

Comment: Depending on Raspberry Pi version you have a 32-bit or a 64-bit CPU and you can't replace it with another CPU without soldering.

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. Also, I thought it came with an ARM CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible and easy to install chromium-bsu simply by installing it from the standard repository:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-bsu
```

At least it is available on Raspbian that way but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be available in the Ubuntu repositories.  What I don't know is how well the game plays on the Raspberry Pi but that's another question.

As for replacing the CPU, no you can't.  It's not possible.